# Pick optimal combination from matrix

Tags: python, matrix, dynamic-programming

Let's say I have a matrix M which looks like:

[a b c l]

[d e f k]

[g h i o]

I have to pick one element from every column such that I can minimise the maximum value of all those elements.

For eg. If I pick a,e,i,k my answer would be max(a,e,i,k)

To find the most optimum solution, is there any approach which is better than O(n^3)?

I would appreciate some sort of pseudocode/snippet of code if possible.

Comment: How about taking the smallest element of each column? This would have O(w*h) with w=width and h=height of the matrix.

Comment: That may not necesarily end up as the most optimal solution as there is the second parameter of only 1 element per column. This is not a greedy problem.

Comment: My solution does minimize the maximum of the possible choices of items. There may be one with better time complexity but the result is optimal (or I'm overseeing something important).

Comment: Let's say a was the lowest valued element of row 1 and g was lowest valued element of row 3. Your approach would always pick a, which may not be the best approach as g would be overlooked. If g was lower than a then it becomes relevant.

Comment: Accidentally I initially wrote "the smallest element of each row" in my first comment but I corrected it to "column". So the rows don't actually matter in my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the minimum value of each column and compute the maximum (M) of those.  Althrough there would be other combinations that produce the same maximum value, M cannot be further reduced because any value in M's column would be larger and picking (smaller) values in other columns would not change M which is the smallest in its own column.

If you were looking to minimize the total of these values, then there would be a need for some additional optimization, perhaps using dynamic programming.  As it is, the problem is simple math.